# getting response is null however it is not null it's having value in nodejs

Tags: node.js

this is my code :in templateController i am getting null value but not null actually.
when i give id value it shows the response is 404.the postman result is{
  "message": "message not found..."
}

var getTemplateController = function(req,res){

```
authToken=req.headers.authorization;
userAuthObj=JSON.parse(UserAuthServices.userAuthTokenValidator(authToken));
var todayDate=new Date();
var expireDate=new Date(userAuthObj.expire_date);
tokenOK=TokenValidator.validateToken(userAuthObj.user_id,authToken).then(function(userSessions){
if (userSessions.length === 1){
    if(expireDate >= todayDate){
        controllerId = req.params.id;
        TemplateController.findById(controllerId).then(function (templateController) {
            if(templateController === null){
                res.status(404).json({
                    message:'message not found...'
                })
            } else {
                res.status(200).json(templateController);
            }
        }).catch(function(err){
            res.status(500).json({
                message:'something went wrong'
            });
        });
    }else{
        res.status(401).json({
            message:'Not Authorized...'
        });
    }
}else{
    res.status(401).json({
        message:'Token Expired...'
    });
}
}).catch(function(err){
    res.status(401).json({
        message:'Token Expired...'
});
});
```

};

Comment: in templateController value is showing null.i don't know how to solve it

Comment: i found solution .i got output